# Configuring a sub-domain DNS in Azure

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

I am new to Azure. I have a linux vm hosted in Azure, on which I am running a springboot application. The springboot app runs behind an Apache httpd.

DNS name for the host is something like **xyz.cloudapp.azure.com** and i need to create a **sub domain (abc.xyz.cloudapp.azure.com)** to host few files on my server. I have made following configuration in the httpd conf to route the requests for sub domain

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName abc.xyz.cloudapp.azure.com
    ServerAlias xyz.cloudapp.azure.com
    DocumentRoot /var/pathforsubdomainfiles
    .......................
    enter code here....................
</VirtualHost>
```

**I am not able to figure out how to create a DNS record for the subdomain (abc.xyz.cloudapp.azure.com) in Azure so that it could be resolved over a public network to access the hosted files.**
I do not have any DNS zones created in Azure yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can [create a fully qualified domain name in the Azure portal for a Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn). The FQDN is something like `abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`. It has a subdomain (abc.xyz.cloudapp.azure.com) in Azure.

If this is not what you desired, you need to purchase a public domain like `example.com` from a domain provider like [GoDaddy](https://sg.godaddy.com/offers/domains/godaddy-b?isc=gotnbsg01&countryview=1&currencyType=SGD&msclkid=a072d0d1432a1e310a3d8e23ecc93b5e&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=en-sg_corp-core_sem_bh_b_exact_new_x_pros_intl_x_001&utm_term=godaddy&utm_content=GD%20Corp%20Core&gclid=CKyL1empmeoCFVU0jgodVhkKhg&gclsrc=ds) and create DNS records to map this subdomain like `www.example.com` to the public IP address or FQDN for the Azure VM because you can not create DNS records for the Azure provided domain `xyz.cloudapp.azure.com`. In the process of creating DNS records, you have a option to [host your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns) and manage your domain in Azure.

For more information, you could read [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-domain-name-to-azure-vm-using-dns-zone/).

Comment: Thank you Nancy for your reply. The DNS that I have is Azure provided and its something like abc.westus.cloudapp.azure.com, which is accessible over public network. I need to configure a sub domain for above mentioned domain which would be something like xyz.abc.westus.cloudapp.azure.com. I need to find a way to configure a DNS in Azure for this sub domain that could be accessed from public network and resolves to an ip same as parent domain. My existing DNS is azure provided and it is not purchased from any external domain provider.

Comment: I mean, you can not configure a subdomain for `xyz.abc.westus.cloudapp.azure.com` because it's parent domain is Azure provided that we can not control over it and it will not be accessed from the public network. You need your own domain to complete the same function refer to the second paragraph in my reply.